# Does the order in which the using directives are listed affect performance of the class?

Tags: c#, class, using

This might seem like a silly question, but I have always wondered if the order in which the using directives (for namespaces) are listed at the top of the class affect the performance of the code running in it?  Or does it just affect compile time/performance?

Comment: Why would you think the order matters?

Comment: No, it definitely doesn't affect runtime performance (the `using` directives are only for the C# compiler; once compiled to CIL byte code, all type names are fully qualified anyway). It shouldn't affect compiler performance either, unless you use a very *very* large number of types from one namespace, in which case it *might* be a fraction faster if you list that namespace first.

Answer (score 1):

No, because there is no norder of a using statement because there is no using statement in a class.

It is purely for the compiler. The using statement does not exist in the bytecode at all.

Answer (score 0):

No, those directives are only needed while writing code and during compilation. You won't find any traces of them afterwards.